# UML to Java code generation tool

Tags: java, uml, code-generation, class-diagram

I have recently been looking for a tool to generate Java code from a UML diagram. I have already looked at Papyrus and Omondo for Eclipse.
The problem I am having is that the tool is needed in a number of projects that are loaded with JPA and JAXB classes. This makes both Omondo and Papyrus come up short, as annotations and getter/setters are fairly important.
What I am looking for is a tool that is able to maintain a graphical class diagram of these projects, like a UML diagram, and then translate that into Java code as needed.

What I am looking for is a reliable *Class diagram* -> *Java code* tool, preferably UML based, that supports (as many as possible of) the following:

- Java primitives (and wrappers)
- Annotations on methods and attributes
- Referencing of Java core classes in class diagram
- Easy getter/setter method generation
- Coding directly in the defined methods

If anyone knows of a tool (it doesn't have to be UML class diagrams) I would very much like to know about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for me the greatest UML tool is [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). It is very powerful. Based on Java.
It constantly improved and become more and more useful tool.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/) you should check out the JPA Diagram Editor that is part of the [**Dali**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) project which as part of the [**Web Tools Platform**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).  This allows you to work directly with your JPA entities in diagram form.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project_Tutorial

The Dali project also has tooling support for JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

Why not looking at BoUml....quite nice and really fast.

[The link](http://www.bouml.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

I have generated Java from UML static/structurel Diagrams using [Poseidon for UML](http://www.gentleware.com/products.html) and [Objecteering](http://www.objecteering.com/).